# Html5 canvas text interactive?

Tags: html, canvas

How do I make html5 canvas filltext interactive? I want them to behave like this: when the mouse hovers on them, they should display a different color, when the mouse clicks on it, it should execute some script.

Comment: I have been working on this for a long time, and it needs a lot of JavaScript coding. First need to get the X and Y positon of your mouse. Trigger event for position to know if it match the position of your texe. There is is no like document.getElementById as canvas is a bitmap.

Comment: OMG... that's what I am worried about... But thanks for letting me know! I will code it little by little thought it looks like a daunting amount of labor!

Comment: Yes i know, there is thing easier to do in Canvas but the trigger event is the hard part. I came trough something that work just fine but I am not going to poste it here as there is a lot of stuff in it and still working on it. Hope one day i'll make it to public so pepople can help me to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

But what I could suggest you, you could use this free open source editor and it does everything in canvas.

http://www.scirra.com/construct2

Well it is free at some point like everything else.
There is a nice tutorial on it, and kind of easy to use.

It only depend what you want to do. For arcade game it is excellent.